# Why does a context object of Entity Framework can access its properties when declared inside controller but not in repository?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework. I am trying it using with ASP.NET MVC. When I create an object of Entity Framework model class, i.e. context in controller then context can access it properties i.e. modelnames, `SaveChanges` property etc but when I use it inside a repository i.e. `InfoLayerRepository` then context doesn't access anything even though initialized.

Why?

Inside controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    EFTestEntities context = new EFTestEntities();

    Info info = new Info()
    {
        Name = "Hunain",
        FatherName = "Hafeez Ullah Khan"
    };

    context.Info.Add(info);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return View();
```

}

Inside repo:

```
using EFTest.Models;

namespace EFTest.DAL
{
    public class InfoLayer
    {
        EFTestEntities context = new EFTestEntities();

        Info info = new Info()
        {
            Name= "Hunain",
            FatherName= "Hafeez Ullah Khan"
        };
    }
}
```

Note: I have kept my entity data model inside Models folders of MVC.

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: *Doesn't access* is vague. It can be a compiler error, an IntelliSense issue or a wrong runtime behavior. Please clarify to get help.